# Cambiar el texto de un botón dependiendo si el subdirectorio está en inglés o español

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problema:**
Que el texto de un botón cambie dependiendo si la URL del sitio web contiene el subdirectorio /es/ referido a español.
El sitio está predeterminado en Inglés.

**Intentos:**
Si la URL tiene subdirectorio /es/ (de español) ejecutar la función Jquery o su equivalente en JS para que el texto aparezca en Español, sino ejecutar la función Jquery o su equivalente en JS para que el texto aparezca en Inglés
Probé escribiendo este código y no me ha funcionado.

**¿Me pueden dar tips para intentarlo y lograrlo?**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(document.url.indexOf("/es/") != -1) { 
        jQuery(function($){
        $("#top-nav").append('<a href="https://sitio.com/free/es/" class="custom-button">GRATIS</a>');
    });
    } 
    else { 
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#top-nav").append('<a href="https://sitio.com/free/" class="custom-button">FREE</a>');
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

la porción de tu código funciona, el problema radica en la función
document.url.indexOf("/es/")

la forma correcta es
document.URL.indexOf("/es/")

porque la función url en minúscula no existe

también puedes probar con
document.location.href.indexOf("/es/")

Comment: Saludos, no me ha funcionado mi estimado. Gracias por intentarlo

Comment: Aunque al OP no le haya funcionado el código, debes explicar brevemente qué hace (ten en cuenta que [es.so] no es un servicio de código, y que otros usuarios encontrarán esta respuesta y no comprenderán su funcionamiento). Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.